# Inactive tab seems to be removing listeners

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, browser

If my browser tab is inactive for approximately 30 minutes or more then it is not catching errors in the HTTP intercepter and doing proper error handling.
Not sure if the browser is removing listeners/optimizing code when the tab is inactive for a long time.
If anyone has any solution then please let me know.

Comment: did you cross-check between browsers?  any logging/error output?

Comment: is there any `requestAnimationFrame` or other interval code involved ??

Comment: Tested in chrome alone. I am handling 401 error in HTTP-interceptor to get new token. But it is not reaching http-interceptor in case of 401 after 30 mins of inactivity.

Comment: There is no interval code involved

Comment: Keeping the developer tools open stops this from happening. But if it is closed then the browser optimizes by removing listeners